# ASP.net image server map and local

Tags: asp.net

Hey all i am trying to figure out the best way to get my URL for the image to be displayed.

Below is my URL in code behind:

```
imgURL = Request.ApplicationPath & "public/themes/_images/" & theCatagory & "_" & productName & ".jpg"
```

However, it only produces **/public/themes/_images/hoods_Fire-Star.jpg** when i am looking to get **http://www.blahblah.com/public/themes/_images/hoods_Fire-Star.jpg**

I save the image like so to the database:

```
Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH").ToString.Replace("\admin", "") & "public\themes\_images\" & theCatagory & "_"
```

That places it here: **C:\Clients\theclient\blahblahblah.com\public\themes_images\hoods_Fire-Star.jpg**

So what do i need to put in the code behind in order to get that URL path with the http?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HOST` http header from the request, though it will not include the protocol.

```
Request.Headers["HOST"]
```

You should be able to figure out the protocol from the current URL.